# Flutter - How to create headers filter in datatable

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make an application with `flutter datatable` but I don't know how to add filter to `column header`

```
rows: users
    .map(
      (user) => DataRow(
              selected: selectedUsers.contains(user),
              onSelectChanged: (b) {
                print("Onselect");
                onSelectedRow(b, user);
              },
              cells: [
                DataCell(
                  //Text(user.firstName),
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      print("First text field: $text");
                      user.firstName = text;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                DataCell(
                  Text(user.lastName),
                ),
              ]),
    )
    .toList(),
),
```

For easier i take an image of example project [Example datatable flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HIrb.png) and on redbox i want add a textfied to filter datatable when textfield of each column change

Comment: What sort of filter, is it normal sorting filter or something else?

Comment: filter means search ?

Comment: it same with filter search, but i don't want use 1 text field for search, i have very much column about 40 column so it will be very hard to set search in this, so i want filter search in header to easy and less code

Comment: thats called sorting its not filtering

Answer (score -3):

It seems that you are trying to implement sorting. You can check [this guide](https://medium.com/@aervadiyayash510/datatable-in-flutter-916ef8081651) for implementing [DataTable](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html) with sorting. Here is an example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Superheros(),
    );
  }
}

class Superheros extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SuperherosState createState() => _SuperherosState();
}

class _SuperherosState extends State<Superheros> {
  late List<Avengers> avengers;
  late List<Avengers> selectedAvengers;
  late bool sort;

  @override
  void initState() {
    sort = false;
    selectedAvengers = [];
    avengers = Avengers.getAvengers();
    super.initState();
  }

  onSortColum(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
    if (columnIndex == 0) {
      if (ascending) {
        avengers.sort((a, b) => a.name.compareTo(b.name));
      } else {
        avengers.sort((a, b) => b.name.compareTo(a.name));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Avengers DataTable"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        child: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0),
            child: DataTable(
              sortAscending: sort,
              sortColumnIndex: 0,
              columns: [
                DataColumn(
                    label: Text("Name", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                    numeric: false,
                    onSort: (columnIndex, ascending) {
                      setState(() {
                        sort = !sort;
                      });
                      onSortColum(columnIndex, ascending);
                    }),
                DataColumn(
                  label: Text("Weapons", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                  numeric: false,
                ),
              ],
              rows: avengers
                  .map(
                    (avenger) => DataRow(
                        selected: selectedAvengers.contains(avenger),
                        cells: [
                          DataCell(
                            Text(avenger.name),
                            onTap: () {
                              print('Selected ${avenger.name}');
                            },
                          ),
                          DataCell(
                            Text(avenger.weapon),
                          ),
                        ]),
                  )
                  .toList(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Avengers {
  String name;
  String weapon;

  Avengers({required this.name, required this.weapon});

  static List<Avengers> getAvengers() {
    return <Avengers>[
      Avengers(name: "Captain America", weapon: "Shield"),
      Avengers(name: "Thor", weapon: "Mjolnir"),
      Avengers(name: "Spiderman", weapon: "Web Shooters"),
      Avengers(name: "Doctor Strange ", weapon: "Eye Of Agamotto"),
    ];
  }
}
```

[image]